# change a select value and submit a form with php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms, select, submit

I have some link buttons on the page beneath my form, within the form container is a dropdown box and a submit button, depending on what link below the form is clicked i wish to change the select and submit the form. Note i am not looking for change select and autosubmit types of solutions, just i click the link it changes the select option and then submits this selected value with the form. I also am not interested in a solution which uses hidden fields as the action to deal with the form is already functioning as required.

Craig

Comment: What you have tried till now?

Comment: StackOverflow.com is a community which helps you solve problems you find very hard to get rid off. Also, you can ask question to this community which are creative. If you are a beginner then first google it and then try your best before posting a question here.